# How to set datetime with HH:mm:ss = 00:00:00 instead of 12:00:00?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
DateTime a1 = new DateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(txtStartDate.Text).Year, Convert.ToDateTime(txtStartDate.Text).Month, Convert.ToDateTime(txtStartDate.Text).Day, 0, 0, 0);
```

I have tried to change system time from 12 hrs hh to 24 hours HH and restart
web site insert still is 12:00:00

I want 00:00:00

Answer (score 10):

What you're seeing is a *formatting* issue rather than a *data* issue. It really is 00:00:00, but however you're converting it to a string is showing it as 12:00:00, presumably with an implicit "am". Don't forget that a `DateTime` doesn't actually *have* a format in it - it's just the date/time. You can format it appropriately yourself, e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine(a1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

All this aside, I would strongly recommend that you don't create the `DateTime` this way. Personally I prefer to use `DateTime.TryParseExact` or `DateTime.ParseExact` anyway, rather than using "whatever patterns the current culture happens to prefer", but even if you *do* want to parse with `Convert.ToDateTime`, it would be clearer to do it once, and then use the `Date` property to get a `DateTime` with the time set to 0:

```
DateTime a1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStartDate.Text).Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically there is no time as 00:00:00. After 11:59:59 it becomes 12:00:00. Maybe I'm just not understanding what you're trying to do :)

You could have special logic in your code that modifies it such that if it is 12:00:00, then display it as 00:00:00 or something. But out of the box there is no magic or format string that will do this.

Comment: Wrong. 12:00 at midnight (12:00AM) is actually 00:00:00 according to the 24 hour clock format.

Comment: @Yogesh, I know that. I guess I don't understand the question. I thought HH was the way to represent 24 hour mode and it has nothing whatsoever to do with system time. So what's that all about.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify that a bit by specifying a format:

```
DateTime a1 = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0} 00:00:00", "01/27/2011"),
                                         CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

I don't know what format your textbox is, but assuming it is 01/27/2011 (US format) you can change the above snippet to work easily:

```
DateTime a1 = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0} 00:00:00", txtStartDate.Text),
                                         CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Change your `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo` (it implements `IFormatProvider`) to the one you're using. Ideally you should parse the date into a UTC date but that's a different discussion.

[image: datetime]

Answer (score 0):

When you want to add a DateTime Object to a string or want to display it in some form of text, the ToString()-Method is used automatically. The ToString() uses "en-US" as default culture. Ofcourse you can manually call ToString() and parametrise it with any CultureInfo you wish but sometimes that is not possible.

When you access DateTime-objects via Databinding for example, you can't pass any CultureInfo and end up with a date string localised in "en-US". In this case you need to set the CultureInfo for the current thread like:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
```

After this line is called all dates will be localised in "de-DE" as long as you don't manually call ToString() with a different CultureInfo.

Have a read on this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify that

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtStartDate.Text))
            {
                string startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStartDate.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
```